# Console.Write is printing after next command prompt

Tags: c#, winforms, command-line, console

So I have a windows form that needs to also be able to be ran from the console (and silently).

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Clear {
    static class Program {
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        private static extern bool AttachConsole(int pid);
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        private static extern bool AllocConsole();

        /// <summary>
        ///     Main
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="args"></param>
        [STAThread]
        static int Main(string[] args) {
            if (args.Length == 0) {
                Application.EnableVisualStyles();
                Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
                Application.Run(new ClearGui());
            } else if (args[0].Contains("help")) {
                if (!AttachConsole(-1)) { // Attach to an parent process console
                    AllocConsole(); // Alloc a new console
                }
                Console.WriteLine("\n\nsyntax: \"" + AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName + "\" /s");
            } else if (Char.ToLower(args[0][1]).Equals('s')) {
                Console.WriteLine(ClearGui());
            }
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is, when you run it from CMD you get something like this:

```
C:\Users\Me>clear.exe help

C:\Users\Me>

syntax: "clear.exe" /s
```

The second line should be **last**. Why is it printing to the console after the next prompt is called?

Comment: Hey, have you ever figured this one?

Answer (score 1):

The `Output type` of your application is marked as `Windows Application`, but it should be `Console Application`.  Right click on your project and select Properties, then go to the Applications tab.

Comment: It has a winform part too.

Comment: That's what causes the issue you mentioned, due to the way Windows launches your application.  The only way to avoid that is setting it as a `Console Application`.  This does not prevent you app from displaying a form.  The problem is that it always creates a console window for your application, which you'll need to hide if the form is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

What you have created is a static `Console Application` that can open an instance of a `Windows Forms Application`. However, you likely have the output type of your application set to `Windows Forms Application` instead of the correct `Console Application`. This issue should go away once you correct the output type.